# Object Pointer Status After New Constructor Throws Exception - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception, constructor

What is going to be the status of an object pointer when a new class constructor throws an exception in C++?  Take the following code for example:

```
CMyClass * pobjMyClass = (CMyClass *)0xA5A5A5A5;

try
{
    pobjMyClass = new CMyClass(); // Exception thrown in constructor
}
catch ( ... ) {}
```

When this code executes what will the value of `pobjMyClass` be, after the exception is thrown?  A pointer to an invalid instance of `CMyClass`, `0xA5A5A5A5`, `NULL`, some random uninitialized value, or something else?  Thanks.

Comment: Surely you've tried this out?

Comment: @TonyK, trying things out only provides half the answer - how it works on *your* compiler. It's often useful to know how it works universally. C++ is full of pitfalls, and it's good to be cautious.

Comment: Even so, Mark -- surely Jim has tried it out? What happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the exception is thrown before the assignment takes place, pobjMyClass will be whatever it was before - in your case, 0xa5a5a5a5.

Comment: +1 deleting mine because you actually got the right answer first :)

Comment: Well, technically it was a bit asinine of me to post a new answer even though yours was annotated in comments and perfectly fine after the edit. But thanks :)

Comment: To be more exact, there is a sequence point at the exit of the constructor, meaning the side effect of the assignment cannot happen before the constructor returns.  Since the constructor does not return, the assignment never happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is correct on just about any concievable implmentation of exceptions. However, it would be kinda cheesy to write code that counts on that behavior.

Comment: Ted - one would hope that the code would not touch pobjMyClass with a 20-foot-pole if the exception is thrown.

Comment: @T.E.D.:  The standard guarantees this behavior.  Nothing cheesey about it.

Comment: @EboMike:  pobjMyClass is perfectly valid after the catch.  Of course, setting a pointer to anything other than `0`, `NULL`, the return value from `new`, the address-of operator or one-past-the-end of a contiguous array is completely undefined, but that's another story entirely.

Comment: @John, it is, but with a value of 0xa5a5a5a5, it's kinda like tossing a loaded gun around :)

Comment: @John: well, VC++ uses `0xcdcdcdcd` for uninitialized pointers in debug mode. That makes it easy to spot them when you're debugging, while NULL could be a "valid" value.

Comment: Lol, I set the value of the pointer to 0xa5a5a5a5 for demonstration purposes only.  I didn't want to initialize it to `NULL` (as I have in my code) for the example because I wanted to convey the different possibilities I had running through my head.